# How to tell when a Stomp server disconnected from the Stomp.JS client

Tags: stomp, sockjs

I am sending a stomp message over a Sock.JS client. When I disconnect the server I would like a warning message to show up on the client. To do this I have implemented a server side heartbeat

```js
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.heartbeat.outgoing = 20000;
stompClient.heartbeat.incoming = 20000;
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
  ...
}
```

In the Chrome developer console I see the message

```
POST http://localhost:8080/hello/800/8n_btbxb/xhr_streaming net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET sockjs-0.3.min.js:27
Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

How can I capture this error message?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As pointed out by [muttonUp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3696510/muttonup) stomp.js from https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/ will overwrite the onclose handler. On the other hand it provides the option to pass an error-callback on connect:

```js
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    ...
}, function(message) {
    // check message for disconnect
});
```

Since you will get several kinds of errors delivered to your callback, you have to check the message it it was indeed the "Whoops! [...]" which indicates a connection loss.

Comment: this method is also not invoked when the network connectivity is down to the server.

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen works for me, when the network is killed after the connection was already established.

Answer (score 4):

Oops just figured it out I will delete in a bit if it doesn't help others. I needed to use SockJS client instead of the Stomp one...

```
var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
...
socket.onclose = function() {
    console.log('close');
    stompClient.disconnect();
    setConnected();
};
```

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/  then this won't work, as Stomp.JS overwrites the onclose function with its own. but perhaps you are you using a different Stomp library?

Comment: Pointing out to the future reader: the `onclose` callback accepts a function with a single `object` parameter that exposes noteworthy values related to the disconnection such as the closing status code [defined in the WebSocket protocol documentation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-7.4.1).